# Cannot crop lakes with Cartopy

Tags: cartopy

I am trying to draw lakes on a map using Cartopy 0.14 and Shapely 1.5.12. With my custom projection, saving or showing the figure sometimes fails with a stack trace ending with

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cartopy-0.14.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cartopy/crs.py", line 291, in _project_multipolygon
    r = self._project_polygon(geom, src_crs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cartopy-0.14.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cartopy/crs.py", line 330, in _project_polygon
    return self._rings_to_multi_polygon(rings, is_ccw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cartopy-0.14.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cartopy/crs.py", line 589, in _rings_to_multi_polygon
    multi_poly = sgeom.MultiPolygon(polygon_bits)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Shapely-1.5.12-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py", line 62, in __init__
    self._geom, self._ndim = geos_multipolygon_from_polygons(polygons)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Shapely-1.5.12-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py", line 178, in geos_multipolygon_from_polygons
    geom, ndims = polygon.geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Shapely-1.5.12-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 503, in geos_polygon_from_py
    geos_shell, ndim = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)
File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 214, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py (shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:3679)
ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples
```

This happens when the boundary of a lake intersects the boundary of the projection. I was unable to reproduce the behaviour with built-in Cartopy projections. Here is the minimal test case I could come up with:

```python
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
from cartopy import feature as cfeature
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely import geometry as sgeom

class Polyconic(ccrs.Projection):

  NUM_BOUNDARY_SEGMENTS = 30

  def __init__(self, central_longitude, globe=None):
      proj4_params = [
          ('proj', 'poly'),
          ('lon_0', central_longitude)]
      super(Polyconic, self).__init__(proj4_params, globe=globe)
      bounds = self.ToPolygon(self.GetLimits(central_longitude)).bounds
      self._x_limits = bounds[0], bounds[2]
      self._y_limits = bounds[1], bounds[3]
      self._boundary = self.ToPolygon(self.GetDomain(central_longitude)).exterior
      if not self._boundary.is_ccw:
        self._boundary.coords = list(self._boundary.coords)[::-1]

  @staticmethod
  def GetDomain(central_longitude):
    lats = np.linspace(0, +90, Polyconic.NUM_BOUNDARY_SEGMENTS + 1)
    lons = np.linspace(
        central_longitude - 15., central_longitude + 15.,
        Polyconic.NUM_BOUNDARY_SEGMENTS + 1)
    domain = []
    for lat in lats:
      domain.append((central_longitude - 15., lat))
    for lat in reversed(lats):
      domain.append((central_longitude + 15., lat))
    return domain

  @staticmethod
  def GetLimits(central_longitude):
    return [
        (central_longitude - 15., 0.),
        (central_longitude + 15., 0.),
        (central_longitude + 15., +90.),
        (central_longitude - 15., +90.)]

  def ToPolygon(self, polygon):
    return sgeom.Polygon(self.transform_points(
        ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        np.array([p[0] for p in polygon]),
        np.array([p[1] for p in polygon])))

  @property
  def threshold(self):
    return 1e3

  @property
  def boundary(self):
    return self._boundary

  @property
  def x_limits(self):
    return self._x_limits

  @property
  def y_limits(self):
    return self._y_limits


plt.figure()
# ax = plt.axes(projection=Polyconic(180)) works.
ax = plt.axes(projection=Polyconic(0))
lakes = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'lakes', '50m')
ax.add_feature(lakes)
plt.show()
```

I was trying to fix the bug for some time, to no avail. I **think** it stems from the incorrect assumption that `type(polygon)` is `sgeom.Polygon` [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/master/lib/cartopy/crs.py#L583). In fact, the variable is sometimes of type `sgeom.MultiPolygon` or `sgeom.GeometryCollection`.

While we are at it, it seems to me that line 544 of crs.py might use `prep_polygon` and lines 562–577 could be simplified as follows:

```python
            y4 += by
            box = sgeom.box(x3, y3, x4, y4)
            for ring in interior_rings:
                polygon = sgeom.Polygon(ring)
                if polygon.is_valid:
                    # Invert the polygon
                    polygon = box.difference(polygon)
```

My question is: is the bug in my code or in Cartopy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoa! I have finally figured this out. Everything works when I change this fragment:

```
      if not self._boundary.is_ccw:
        self._boundary.coords = list(self._boundary.coords)[::-1]
```

to

```
      if self._boundary.is_ccw:
        self._boundary.coords = list(self._boundary.coords)[::-1]
```

which means that boundaries of projections should be **clockwise**. With hindsight, I could have inferred it from [lines 123–149 of crs.py](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/master/lib/cartopy/crs.py#L123).